# Jenkins: Running groovy script with ant commands

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ant

I have a groovy script with ant commands on it. The script is successfully run in my local machine but when I tried it with Jenkins the groovy script always fail. Jenkins always return error that "ant can't create task or type p4Change". I already added Apache ant support in the global configuration. How do I configure ant to successfully run the groovy script I have. Any idea. Thanks.

Sample code snippets:
I have execute.groovy file with ant commands

```
ant=new AntBuilder()

def checkChanges {
ant.p4change(description:"Checking",port:'perforce:1666',user:optional,view:"'${workspace}'...")}
```

And I created a batch file that will run the execute.groovy file

```
call groovy execute.groovy project bopolz18 -c bopolz18.Workspace 150718
```

In my machine this works well but in Jenkins when I execute the batch command it fails giving the error mention above.

Comment: can you post the code snippet of your ant or groovy??

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy I have edited the question above thanks for your response.

Comment: Something's missing here. Ant's P4 tasks are optional and need to be defined with a `taskdef` before they can be used.

Comment: According to https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/tags/ANT_DOCS_PRE_14/docs/manual/OptionalTasks/perforce.html p4* tasks requires some jar libraries. I Guess you don't have them on Jenkins. Provide the full stacktrace of the error, so it will be clear what exactly is missing.

Comment: Thanks @daggett here is the stacktrace of error:

Caught: : Problem: failed to create task or type p4change
Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.perforce.P4Change was not found.
        This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
        -ANT_HOME\lib
        -the IDE Ant configuration dialogs

Do not panic, this is a common problem.
The commonest cause is a missing JAR.

This is not a bug; it is a configuration problem

Comment: @daggett what do you mean by not having it on jenkins?Where do I add this jars if I'm missing them and also I added ant manually which uses the installation in my machine and I guess it doesn't use it because the script that I have it runs successfully in my machine. Thank you.

Comment: You are starting groovy as a separate process. So, p4 jars should be in a groovy classpath. You can use --classpath parameter for groovy command

Comment: @daggett thank you so much I'm doing it wrong I'm adding the jars in ant classpath wich is supposed to be in groovy. Thank you, now my scripts runs in Jenkins successfully.